# Puppet assign class parameters in multiple places

Tags: puppet

I'm learning puppet (v6), and trying to understand how to set class parameters when a specific node needs an additional parameter, but uses the same class. Maybe a little fuzzy on the terminology, but here's what I'm working on:

`MyNode1` needs sshd configured to use a banner and timeout, so using [ghoneycutt-ssh](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/ghoneycutt/ssh), I include the `ssh` class with parameters:

```
/modules/MyModule/manifests/MySSH.pp

# Configures SSH
class MyModule::MySSH { 
  # Using ssh module
  class { '::ssh':
    sshd_client_alive_count_max => 0,
    sshd_client_alive_interval  => 900,
    sshd_config_banner          => '/etc/MyBanner.txt',
  }
}
```

Now I have a second node `MyNode2`, which requires `MySSH` above, and *also* needs to disable forwarding. I started with something like this, where I define only the additional parameter in its own class:

```
/modules/MyModule/manifests/MySSH_Node2.pp

class MyModule::MySSH_Node2 { 
  class { '::ssh': 
    sshd_allow_tcp_forwarding => 'no', 
  }
}
```

Then define `MyNode2` to include both in my site definition, hoping that puppet merges my `::ssh` definitions:

```
/manifests/site.pp

node MyNode1 {
  include MyModule::MySSH
}
node MyNode2 {
  include MyModule::MySSH
  include MyModule::MySSH_Node2
}
```

I understand that the above example doesn't work due to error `Duplicate declaration: Class[Ssh]`. I also tried overriding the class with a new parameter:

```
class MyModule::MySSH_Node2 { 
  Class[ssh] {
    sshd_allow_tcp_forwarding => 'no', 
  }
}
```

But it seems this is not allowed either: `Error: Resource Override can only operate on resources, got: Class[ssh]-Type`

I'm not sure what the best way to add parameters is. I know I can create a manifest that includes *all* the parameters needed for this node and apply that instead, but then I end up with duplicate code everywhere.

Is there a reasonable way in modern puppet to assign and merge class parameters like this in puppet?

Comment: node1 and node2 should both `include` the `ssh` class with different parameters for each. That would be the cleanest and most effective path forward for you.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Correct me if I'm wrong, but `include` doesn't allow setting parameters?

Comment: It does with automatic parameter lookups combined with Hiera, which is the most common design pattern/architecture, and the one that replaced the deprecated `params.pp` pattern several years ago.